What are these strange rainbow artifacts along the edges and how do I get rid of them?
I'm a total beginner to blender and am trying to create a character model. All I have added is a background and a sphere, but there are these rainbow-colored pixels along the edges of the background and the sphere. This seems like a bug. How can I get rid of these?

Check that your machine's graphics drivers are up to date and compatible with Blender 4.2.

That worked, thank you!

Good! Always the first 'port of call' when you see odd artifacts!
